# symbol recognition

Tags: c++, image-processing

Does any one know how I can get a c++ class for symbol recognition.By symbol recognition I mean things like shaded/unshaded circles, ovals, rectangles, squares,triangles,rhombus , hexagon, octagon ,rhomboid,  cross, star etc.

What I am really interested in is writing  a c++ program that can recognise such shapes in scanned documents.

I will appreciate any , in addition, form of explanation or tutorial on this.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a great place to start. The framework is capable of many image recognition tasks. It can even do complex tasks like facial recognition.

Comment: OpenCV is an C based API library though ;-)

Comment: OpenCV has a C, C++ and python interface. Here's the C++ documentation: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html